# Corda Mainnet node requirements?

Tags: blockchain, corda

Does anyone know what the node requirements for the corda mainnet are? There is a documentation for the corda enterprise framework:

https://docs.r3.com/en/platform/corda/4.8/enterprise/operations/deployment/host-prereq.html

But i can't find any numbers for the mainnet, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The node requirements depend on your requirments. You have to consider various aspects before finalising the node requirements.

For example, it depends on your application requirements how many cores your node must support. The more the cores you increase gives you a better opportunity to run flows in parallel.

Again how much memory/heap you want to allocate affects the performance. The more RAM you have, the more transaction requests your node can support and the larger each of those transactions can be. If the memory is too low you can face the dreaded Java Heap Size Out of Memory error which will crash the node because it can no longer allocate objects.

Below is the table which shows you a recommended size for the nodes.

```
Size    JVM    Heap   #Cores Minimum Host RAM

Small   1GB     1      2GB to 3GB 
Medium  4GB     8      8GB 
Large   32GB    32     64GB 
X-Large >32GB   >32    >64GB
```

Please refer to [this](https://docs.r3.com/en/platform/corda/4.8/enterprise/performance-testing/performance-results.html#sizing) link for more details.